# Automatic email client configuration

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, iphone

I have been looking for an automatic tool for e-mail clients like Outlook, Gmail and iPhone. How could I create a file that I can send to a new user that will setup their e-mail client? Can I use a shell script or is there something already available? I found a link about OCT, but apparantly the microsoft download page is not showing. Yet, I still wonder about iPhone and Gmail.

In the worst case scenario - I'll build something to do such a thing. Where can I look?

Comment: Autodiscover / Exchange ActiveSync much?  You can already configure Outlook and iPhone by simply entering your email address and password.  Gmail isn't an email client.  What's your question?

Comment: Gmail can import POP/SMTP accounts - so it is used as one. My question is how I can automate setup for e-mail users with a one-click solution. I have a hmailserver setup.

Comment: Autodiscover sounds like a good idea - I''ll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Outlook I suggest using a VB script, I don’t do any VBS but you could start reading here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595/en-gb

For g-mail are you just wanting to setup an IMAP account in Outlook as well?

Comment: it is basically for who needs what - not everyone uses Outlook, so I want to offer an alternative. Thanks for the link, I'll check that one out.